# Theme builder vs Bought Theme for Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I've search for many hours now on the internet,

I'm developing Prestashop website for clients, and do you think I should use a Theme builder like Prestabuilder, a theme with a builder like Warehouse & elementor or a pre-made theme that i will custom through code. What's the better for performance, page speed ?

How do you feel about that ? Do you always develop from scratch for client or just install a theme ?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the hot water...

Start with a premium theme e.g. Warehouse which has about 15 different layouts you can choose from each of them can be further changed if you want.

For the price you get clean responsiveness, a bunch of very useful modules (only the megamenu if bought separately costs more than half the theme's price).

It has the famed Elementor page builder and it shortens the development tine 10x.